# I want to put the extras of two different requests in the same activity

Tags: android

At the time I send two requests of two different URLS, I need to put extras on the same activity, but Im launching this Activity two times as a result the first request Activity (extras are different) are replaced by the second one.

The source code is something like this:

```
request.checkPlayerName(buscar, new ApiRequest.CheckPlayerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String name, long summonerLevel, int profileIconId, long id) {
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EstadisticasActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("NAME", name);
        extras.putLong("SUMMONERLEVEL", summonerLevel);
        extras.putInt("PROFILEICONID", profileIconId);
        extras.putLong("ID", id);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void dontExist(String message) {
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

request.checkPlayerLeague(new ApiRequest.CheckLeagueCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String tier, int leaguePoints, String rank) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EstadisticasActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("TIER", tier);
        extras.putInt("LEAGUEPOINTS", leaguePoints);
        extras.putString("RANK", rank);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the problem you face?

Comment: launching same activity two times at the same time for what purpose?

Comment: You do two HTTP requests and want to wait for both to finish and put the aggregated results as the extras for a new activity? But you currently don't aggregate the results of the two requests and open the new Activity for each of the results?

Comment: I want to launch activity only 1 time, but I can't start Activity in the second one only or vice versa cause I can't show the first one extras. I want to group all extras an show at the same time. It works for separately if I comment anyone of the startActivity(intent);